About preventing errors in use of Range adaptor objects
The code below compiles, but is meaningless and clearly indicates that the programmer made a typo:
std::vector a{ 1, 2, 3};
auto        x = std::views::take(a);
auto        y = std::views::drop(a);
auto        z = std::views::transform(a);

Why are such errors not prevented by the std?
Maybe for those views whose call signature has additional arguments besides  ranges themselves (take_view, drop_view, transform_view, etc.), it makes sense to make an additional abstraction - Range adapter factories, the call signature of which will contain only the above additional arguments, and which will create Range adapter objects for these arguments

P2325R3 agrees with you. It was adopted but the various views have not had the default constructor removed yet.

So... it's at least easy to see how you would reject take(a) and drop(a). But transform(a) is a bit more challenging - since you'd need to check to make sure a is vaguely invocable, and there are a lot of ways for that to be the case (function pointer, pointer to member, type with call operator, type with conversion function to function pointer...). And even then, transform([](int x, int y){ return x + y; }) is also likewise meaningless. But does seem nice to be able to catch more cases.

@Barry Thank you very much! std::is_invocable_r couldn't help?

@Pavel not without type arguments


The code below compiles, but is meaningless

It's true that x, y and z are basically unusable, but it's a hard problem to distinguish them from things that aren't.
The compiler has to be able to come to a conclusion like "For all types, T, the expression std::declval<T>() | x is ill-formed.". At the moment, there isn't even a syntax to express that.

Why are such errors not prevented by the std?

Because the committee doesn't have time to think about all the useless things that could be written, especially as compilers already have options for flagging unused variables.

"difference_type is (implicitly convertible from) std::vector<int>" - that's not possible. For any given implementation, the set of permissible difference_types is closed and known to the implementation.

@T.C. ? What's stopping someone writing class MyRange { using difference_type = MyBigIntType; ... };, and MyBigIntType having a constructor from std::vector<int>?

An iterator doing that won't be weakly_incrementable.
